# Flutter/Dart: Bad State errors when trying to close down a stream pipeline

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, stream

I'm building a mobile app in flutter which pipes the mic audio (`mic_stream` lib) to a websocket. I’m really struggling to close down the stream pipeline when I'm done with it. I’m getting various “Bad State” exceptions such as `Cannot add event while adding a stream`. The particulars depend on how I set up the pipeline but it seems to be at the root because the returned `addStream` future never completes.  Any ideas what would cause that?

As said above, the source stream is from the `mic_stream` lib which pulls from native via  Flutter's `EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream`. The docs for this method says its returned stream will only close down when there are no more listeners. I try closing my websocket and get a similar error for the same reason (websocket internal bad state b/c addStream never completes). I'm tried wrapping the mic stream in a `StreamController` and closing *that* but I get the error mentioned above.

Starting to feel like it's a bug. Maybe `EventChannel`'s stream is special? Or is it related to it being a "broadcast" stream.

Feeling stuck. Any help appreciated...thx

Answer (score 1):

Flutter makes this a little confusing by returning a stream from EventChannel that you can't really use in the normal pipeline chaining way if you ever need to close it. Perhaps they should have done internally what I'm about to show as the workaround.

First for clarity, when you use `addStream` on `StreamController` (`StreamConsumer` rather) it blocks you from "manual" control via the `add()` method and also the `close()` *until that stream completes*. This makes sense, if you think about it, since the source stream should determine when it closes. That's why `addStream()` returns a `Future` – so you know when you can resume using those methods, or add another stream. Doing so beforehand will trigger the `Bad State` errors mentioned above.

From the docs for `EventChannel::receiveBroadcastStream()`...

> Stream activation happens only when stream listener count changes from 0 to 1. **Stream deactivation happens only when stream listener count changes from 1 to 0.**

So *we* need to decide when it is done, and to do this we need to control its subscription rather than bury it in a pipeline or a StreamController's private internals via the `addStream()` method. So instead we'll listen to it directly, capturing the subscription to close when we're done. Then we just proxy the data into a StreamController or pipeline manually via `add()`

```dart
Stream<Uint8List> micStream = await MicStream.microphone(
    sampleRate: AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE,
    channelConfig: ChannelConfig.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
    audioFormat: AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);//,
    // audioSource: AudioSource.MIC);  // ios only supports default at the mo'

StreamController? s;

// We need to control the listener subscription 
// so we can end this stream as per the docs instructions
final micListener = micStream.listen((event) {
  print('emitting...');

  // Feed the streamcon manually
  s!.add(event);
});

s= StreamController();

// Let the SCon's close() trigger the Listener's cancel()
s!.onCancel = () {
  print("onCancel");
  micListener.cancel();
};
s!.done.whenComplete(() {
  print("done");
});

// Further consumers will use the _StreamCon's_ stream, 
// _not_ the micStream above
s!.stream.listen((event) => print("listening..."));


// Now we can close the StreamController when we are done.
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  s!.close();
});
```